# Calling SignalR Hub method from code behind

Tags: asp.net, webforms, signalr

I had a  web Application with master page and I need to show a alert to all connected users of my application. I had used the Owin startup class and mapped signal R

Then created a Hub like below

```
    namespace ArtWebApp
{
    [HubName("artHub")]
    public class ArtWebHub : Hub
    {

        public void Hello()
        {
            Clients.All.hello();
        }


        public void SayMessage()
        {
            this.Clients.All.showmessage();

        }
    }
}
```

Then in the masterpage I added the  Javascript as below

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            debugger;
            var connection = $.hubConnection("")
            var hub = connection.createHubProxy('artHub');
            hub.on('showmessage', function () {

                alert('Hi');
            });


            connection.start().done();
            //connection.start(function () {

            //    hub.invoke('SayMessage');
            //});
        });

    </script>
```

This is working perfectly when the Hub method is invoked from the same page but when I tried to call the method from button click of a page its not working

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ArtWebApp.ArtWebHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.All.SayMessage();    
    }
```

Can somebody suggest me the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What i can see from your code is a mistake on the client side function you are calling.

`Clients.All` typically lets you invoke a function you have defined at the client side by calling `Clients.All.functionName()`

In the `Button1_Click` event please change

```
 hubContext.Clients.All.SayMessage();
```

To

```
 hubContext.Clients.All.showMessage();
```

This is because you are using the `dynamic` collection `Clients`

You are trying to invoke a client side function (which doesn't exist).

The method SayMessage you are trying to call is a member of the ArtWebHub class and cannot be invoked by calling `hubContext.Clients.All`.

You can invoke `SayMessage` from the client using `hub.invoke('SayMessage')` but to invoke the `showmessage` function defined in the client you'll have to invoke it differently from the server because `SayMessage` is not available to the `hubContext`

Comment: Thanks for answer .The issue is solved and Signalr is working for almost all pages from masterpage. But at some pages I am getting a error "Object doesnt support property or Method hubconnection" can you suggest me anything

Comment: @SreenathGanga Be sure to check that you've loaded the SignalR client library on those pages. That is usually the problem when you get that error.

Comment: I had defined it in the master page  with absolute url                             <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js"></script>

Comment: @SreenathGanga you have to confirm that it loads properly on the pages where it's failing.